# Using JAXB, marshal nested element in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, marshalling

### I would like to get a xml result as below which using JAXB to get java object.

```
<Mall>
  <ProductInfo>
     <Product>
       <name>chair</name>
       <price>150</price>
     </Product>
 </ProductInfo>
</Mall>
```

---

To get this result, I made 3 java classes which are

1. Define `XmlRootElement`, `XmlElement`
2. component of product (getter/setter)
3. Main class which insert the value of component

In this way, I could make only 3 depths using `XmlRootElement`, `XmlElement`, Component of product.

Hence I need one more depth..
I tried to use a `XmlElementWrapper` to give one more depth, but there was an error regarding it is not a collecting attribute...

Please help me to solve this out...

Answer (score 0):

Below is class structure that should work

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "mall")
public class Mall {
    Mall(){  }

    @XmlElement(name="ProductInfo")
    private ProductInfo info; // must create getter and setter
    }
}

public class ProductInfo {  // you should be missing this
    ProductInfo(){
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Product")
    private List<Product> info; // must create getter and setter
    }
}

public class Product {
    Product(){
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    private ProductInfo info; // must create getter and setter

    @XmlElement(name="price")
    private ProductInfo info; // must create getter and setter

    }
}
```